# Unique solution to a boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, hamilton-equations

Let consider a hamiltonian system on $[0,T]$ (resulting from Pontryaging Maximum Principle)
($q=(q_1,q_2)$ is the state and $p=(p_1,p_2)$ is the co-state)

$$
\frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}(q,p), \quad \frac{dp}{dt} = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial q}(q,p)
$$

A solution of this system have to check some **boundary conditions** such as
\begin{align*}
&q_2(0)=0, \; q_2(T)=q_{2T}, \\
&q_1(0)=q_1(T), \; p_1(0)=p_1(T).
\end{align*}
(4 conditions in dimension 4)

*Do you have some general/heuristic ideas to prove that on a fix level of energy $H$, there exists  at most one solution ?*

Thanks